# CentOS 6 - How to modify iptables during kickstart install?

Tags: centos, iptables, rpm, kickstart

I'm having trouble modifying iptables configuration during a customized kickstart installation of CentOS 6.   The kickstart process is installing several custom RPMs on top of a minimal ISO image.  One of the rpms attempts to modify the iptables rules but after Anaconda completes the installation, the original default rules are still set in /etc/sysconfig/iptables.

I've tried using iptables (save|restore) but the iptables modules aren't available during the installation.  `iptables -L` returns the error "can't initialize iptables 'filter': Table does not exist" and both save/restore commands fail to run.

After poking around I realized that the package system-config-firewall-base is installed and seems to be setting the default rules.  Further, I see that my rules have been copied into `/etc/sysconfig/iptables.old` but I can't figure out what is causing that.  I've tried adding `Requires: system-config-firewall-base` to my package in the hopes that I could change the rules in my %post after they've been set but that didn't work.

Installing this package *after* first boot sets up the rules correctly.

Any advice on how to correctly configure iptables during installation or else how to configure something to achieve this automatically on first boot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You best bet is to  edit the /etc/sysconfig/iptables file directly in a script in the %post section of your kickstart file.  This will run after you have installed your packages.

Comment: Right, I've tried that and once installation completes, I switch over to VT2 to inspect the filesystem and /mnt/sysimage/etc/sysconfig/iptables contains the old, default settings.

Comment: I retried this approach and it seems to work.  Not sure why my first attempt failed, but copying the custom iptables rules in a `%post --nochroot` kickstart section seems to work.

Comment: Ya I wondered if it had something to do with the root jail, good to know that it works without the root jail.

Answer (score 1):

What firewall mods are you trying to do?

You can make firewall mods with kickstart

Ex to enable ssh (tcp 22) and http (tcp 80) put the following line in your kickstart

firewall --enabled --http --ssh

Comment: Our edits require more complicated changes than enabling specific ports.

Comment: What do they require?

Comment: We need to deploy custom firewall configurations based on the host type.  The individual configuration is more complicated than opening access for specific services.

Answer (score -1):

I'll point out that there is a programmatic API for editing the iptables config file

Here is an example:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8880 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
service iptables restart
```

Comment: This could suffer from a race condition if multiple users are running scripts like this. Better to change `iptables-save >/etc/sysconfig/iptables` to `command service iptables save`, and get rid of the `restart`.

Comment: @MarkLakata while kind of a corner case, still nice to know about the `save` command. I'm curious about your use of the `command` command. What is the purpose of doing it that way and not just `service iptables save`

Comment: No good reason, it was just something I cut and paste from some other SO article :). I just learned what the purpose of the 'command' command is -- to prevent some alias called `service` to interfere. See http://ss64.com/bash/command.html

Comment: Yea... that was what i was thinking... Preventing someone from hijacking your `service` command somehow.

Comment: This doesn't address the original problem. If you try to run these commands during the kickstart phase you will get "can't initialize iptables 'filter': Table does not exist" as already mentioned in the question.